# Gateway Windows XP Media Center boot restore not available

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, system-restore, gateway, factory-defaults

I was using a Gateway PC to install Ubuntu on a secondary hard drive. I'm still able to access the installed version of XP but the (I beleive it was f11) option for factory restore is now missing.  The restore partition is located on the D drive and I do not have a system restore.  How can restore the factory setting of XP Media Center?